# SQL lag statement taking too long to run on Azure SQLDB

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a statement as follows

```
SELECT H.[StorageItemId]
  ,H.[FullyQualifiedName]
      ,V.DateTime
     ,V.Value        
         --,lag(V.Value) over (order by V.DateTime) as prevVal
FROM [dbo].[History_StorageItem] as H 
JOIN [dbo].[History_Integer] as V  on H.StorageItemId = V.StorageItemId 
where H.FullyQualifiedName like '%.Flt_No'
   and  V.QualityDetail=192 and V.DateTime>getdate() -8
```

If I comment the lag part I get about 50 records and it runs in seconds. But when I include the lag part, the query takes about 5 mins to execute. The pricing Tier on Azure is premium p4 with 500 DTUS. But I didn't think a lag of 50 records would take this long.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try subquery/cte:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT H.[StorageItemId]
      ,H.[FullyQualifiedName]
      ,V.DateTime
      ,V.Value        
    FROM [dbo].[History_StorageItem] as H 
    JOIN [dbo].[History_Integer] as V  
      on H.StorageItemId = V.StorageItemId
    where H.FullyQualifiedName like '%.Flt_No'    -- notSargable condition
      and V.QualityDetail=192 
      and V.DateTime > getdate()-8
)
SELECT *,  lag(Value) over (order by DateTime) as prevVal
FROM cte;
```

This should change execution plan a bit. Unfortunately there is no [force intermediate materialization of CTE](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891374-provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materializati) hint.

---

Another option is using temp table:

```
SELECT H.[StorageItemId]
  ,H.[FullyQualifiedName]
  ,V.DateTime
  ,V.Value     
INTO #temp   
FROM [dbo].[History_StorageItem] as H 
JOIN [dbo].[History_Integer] as V  
  on H.StorageItemId = V.StorageItemId
where H.FullyQualifiedName like '%.Flt_No'    -- notSargable condition
  and V.QualityDetail=192 
  and V.DateTime > getdate()-8;

SELECT *,  lag(Value) over (order by DateTime) as prevVal
FROM #temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

> f I comment the lag part I get about 50 records and it runs in seconds

For a window function to work efficiently, you should have a POC index..

so for your query to work well ,i would recommend below index on history_integer table

```
create index nci on dbo.history_integer(value,datetime) include
(rest of columns in select )
```

There is a tradeoff with the above index, this index works well for your partition clause,but same index doesn't help you, if your where clause filters a lot of data...